# Loading Packages in a Progn in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to make a simple form that will automate the loading of Slynk on an image.

So far, I have this:

```
(progn 
    (load "/home/user/asdf.lisp")
    (format t "~% Loaded ASDF")
    (push "/home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/sly-20180708.712/slynk/" asdf:*central-registry*)
    (format t "~% Added SLYNK path to ASDF:*CENTRAL-REGISTRY*")
    (asdf:load-system :slynk)
    (format t "~% Loaded ASDF system")
    (slynk:create-server :port 4007  :dont-close t)
    (format t "~% Created SLYNK server on port 4007")
    (setf slynk:*use-dedicated-output-stream* nil)
    (format t "~% Set *USE-DEDICATED-OUTPUT-STREAM* to NIL"))
```

The issue is that whenever I try to evaluate this form at the REPL, I get the following error:

```
Error: "ASDF" is not a known package.

Restart actions (select using :continue):
 0: Return NIL
 1: Return to Top Level (an "abort" restart).
 2: Abort entirely from this (lisp) process.
[1] CL-USER(4):
```

No prints yet appear prior to that point. That is, it seems to error on the first `push` line. My understanding is that it has not yet loaded the package and tries to refer to its symbol.

How can I change the form to make it work? There are similar situations lower in the form.

P.S. When each line is executed by itself in the given order, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error comes from [`read`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) as
it tries to parse the whole `progn` form and [sees the `asdf:` package prefix](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_ce.htm).

You must load `asdf` *before* the reader sees the code with the
`asdf:` package prefix *and* load `slynk` *before* you use the `:slynk`
prefix, in other words, feed your `progn` forms to Lisp **one by one** (as you say in your PS).

Another way is to put everything inside your `progn` in a **separate
file** and load it.  You would also want to make `"20180708.712"` and `4007` variables, e.g.,

```
(defvar *sly-version* "20180708.712")
(defvar *slynk-port* 4007)
(load "load-and-start-slynk.lisp")
```

and in `load-and-start-slynk.lisp`:

```
(load "/home/user/asdf.lisp")
(format t "~% Loaded ASDF")
(push (concatenate 'string "/home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/sly-"
                   *sly-version* "/slynk/")
      asdf:*central-registry*)
(format t "~% Added SLYNK path to ASDF:*CENTRAL-REGISTRY*")
(asdf:load-system :slynk)
(format t "~% Loaded ASDF system")
(slynk:create-server :port *slynk-port* :dont-close t)
(format t "~% Created SLYNK server on port ~D" *slynk-port*)
(setq slynk:*use-dedicated-output-stream* nil)
(format t "~% Set *USE-DEDICATED-OUTPUT-STREAM* to NIL")
```

PS. Just to show how to *abuse* Lisp power, here is how to do what you are trying to do:

```
(defun load-and-start-slynk (port version)
  (load "/home/user/asdf.lisp")
  (format t "~% Loaded ASDF")
  (push (concatenate 'string "/home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/sly-" version "/slynk/")
        (symbol-value (find-symbol "*CENTRAL-REGISTRY*" '#:asdf)))
  (format t "~% Added SLYNK path to ASDF:*CENTRAL-REGISTRY*")
  (funcall (find-symbol "LOAD-SYSTEM" '#:asdf) :slynk)
  (format t "~% Loaded ASDF system")
  (funcall (find-symbol "CREATE-SERVER" '#:slynk) :port port :dont-close t)
  (format t "~% Created SLYNK server on port ~D" port)
  (setf (symbol-value (find-symbol "*USE-DEDICATED-OUTPUT-STREAM*" '#:slynk)) nil)
  (format t "~% Set *USE-DEDICATED-OUTPUT-STREAM* to NIL"))
```

Do ***not*** do this.

Comment: Are there any hacks to keep it as a single form and copy-pasteable?

Comment: Yes but the hack is ugly, please see PS.

Comment: sds's suggestion to just put it all in a file which you load is a good one.  Then you have a single form: `(load "/home/user/slynk-loader.lisp")` say.

Comment: The problem with doing that is that I sometime start the server on different ports. But I heed your suggestion.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I made the port variable.

Comment: @sds Btw, I am wondering why you decided to parametrize the Slynk version as well. Is it common to have different versions installed? Are the there substantial differences from one to another?

Comment: The version changes every time you update your packages (`M-x p-l-p RET U X`)

Comment: I see. I must not update very often. By the way, when I try the code you provided, I get an error: `CL-USER(49): (find-symbol '#:*central-registry* '#:asdf)
Error: Can't coerce #:*CENTRAL-REGISTRY* to type
       SIMPLE-STRING.`